# Exported xls file from java has time appended with date, even though the db column has date only

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi, xls

When trying to export an xls file by java using Apache POI I'm getting date as well as time in a column, although there is no time present in DB for that column, only the date is present. The column datatype in db is 'DATE'. The java code is implicitly adding the time in the xls as in:

```
2012-12-13 00:00:00.0
```

Whereas the db column only has:

```
13-DEC-12
```

I want the same format to be preserved in the xls file, or at least devoid of the time.

Comment: You'll need to post some code so we can see what you're doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It is not the fault of the java code. Excel do not have a date only data type. It only have DateTime. Just change the format in the cells and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry but manual formatting doesn't work. The column remains unaffected as in 2012-12-13 00:00:00.0.

 Is there any way to get just the date programmatically using Apache POI?